# Desktop size larger than display area winxp

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, graphics-card

I have an Acer Aspire SA85 with SIS661 on board VGA graphics with a Viewsonic VX2235wm monitor.  The natural resolution of the monitor is 1680 by 1050.  However, when set to this the monitor only shows part of the screen, with the picture panning when the cursor hits the sides or top or bottom.  I've reinstalled the video driver and driver for the monitor.  No problem is reported in device manager.  The SIS utility manager shows this mode to be correct.  I've even gone as far as to re-format my hard drive and re-install windows xp from scratch.  The problem remains.  Can anyone help?
Cheers,
Stuart

Answer (score 0):

might need an updated driver. go to the manufacturers website to obtain the latest graphics card driver and install that. I've also had problems like this where all it took was a simple restart after installing the driver.

Comment: Thanks for that. But I've already tried the latest driver from the motherboad manufacturer.  Yes, I've started the computer many times since the new driver was installed, no change.

Comment: Update.  I've re-installed the driver, this time from the chip set manufacturer, not the motherboard manufacture, (I had tried this earlier) and the problem is solved, - partly.  The whole desktop now fits the screen and has the right resolution but text looks crappy, as if the resolution is not the natural resolution of the monitor, which it is; 1680 * 1050.  Better, but still not fixed.

Comment: Solved! I noticed that the image on the screen did not go all the way to the edges horizontally by about 2mm.  I chose "Auto Image Adjust" on the monitor's menu and now the text is good and the picture fills the screen exactly.